# Looking for lightweight portable WiFi router

Tags: wifi, router, portable

Some basic searches:

- https://lifehacker.com/five-best-travel-routers-1452441479
- https://www.techhive.com/article/2150741/laptop-accessories/tested-6-new-travel-routers-that-can-deploy-a-secure-wi-fi-network-almost-anywhere.html

My main use scenario: traveling to some place where with no WiFi. Going to internet cafe that has some old computers connected via ethernet cable but again - no WiFi. iPhones and MacBooks don't have ethernet cable so I would like to transparently plug into existing wired connection and access internet on my devices.

**Requirements for the router:**

- ethernet in
- ethernet out
- powered from battery pack
- (optional nice to have) https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet - I don't think it is widely available just yet...

Some potential candidates / no affiliates / collected from links on the top:

- [https://www.amazon.com/BR-6258n-150Mbps-Wireless-Broadband-Supported/dp/B0069JA7M2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0069JA7M2)
- https://www.amazon.co.uk/NETGEAR-PR2000-100EUS-Universal-Extender-Travel/dp/B00I4UQ0AC

They are both reasonably priced. Are there any other models / any other considerations?

Comment: I would look at the Google onhub but it does not have a battery pack and it is 200$

Comment: @AidenGrossman have you read the use case and requirements?